# Mean value of a function using Cauchy Integral Formula

Tags: complex-analysis, means

$f:U\rightarrow \mathbb C$ is holomorphic. Let $U=\{z\in \mathbb C : |z-a|\leq r \}$.

> Deduce that $f(a)$ is the mean of the values of $f$ on the circle $|z-a|= r$

I parametrized $z=a+re^{it}$. Then $dz=ire^{it}dt$

Using Cauchy Int. Formula:

$$f(a)=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint f(z)/(z-a)dz=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_0^{2\pi} if(a+re^{it})=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(a+re^{it})$$

Is this the answer they are looking for, in which case I don't undertand why this is the average value.

Comment: Do you mean 'the disc $|z-a| \leq r$' or 'the circle $|z-a|=r$'?  What you have on the right is the average on the latter, as the average along any (suitable) curve is $$ \frac{1}{\mbox{length}(\gamma)} \int_\gamma f(z) \, \mathrm{d}z.$$

Comment: But in my case the circumference is $2 \pi r $ which is not $2\pi $, also how is the integral the same as summing up all values? I could imagine the integral being the area of a circle, which is not the case in complex

Comment: The $r$ disappears due to the parameterisation correction term.

Comment: @MichaelCoffey thanks, but I still don't see why $r$ disappears. Does it happen for all such complex integrals? The mean value is $1/2\pi i$? P.S. I edited the question to be a circle

Comment: What you have on the right hand side is equal to $$\frac{1}{2 \pi r} \int_{\partial U} f(z) \, |\mathrm{d} z|.$$ Try evaluating this integral yourself directly from the definition of a complex integral, and you'll see where the $r$ cancels.  This won't be the case for all complex integrals - it just so happens that $$\left | \frac{d}{dt}(a+re^{it}) \right |=\left |i\mathbf{r}e^{it}\right | = r. $$  Btw, above (second comment), that should be $|dz|$, not $dz$.

Comment: @Michael Coffey thanks a lot :)

Comment: By the way, this has a direct link to the mean value property for harmonic functions (check out any first course in PDE, or just wikipedia).  That $f$ is holomorphic implies its real and imaginary parts are harmonic (i.e. $\Delta u, \Delta v = 0$ on $U$ where $f=u+iv$), which follows from the Cauchy-Riemann equations.